# jquery drag image

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-ui

i want to make a draggable image in jquery. 
first of all my experience with jquery is 0. having said that let me describe what i want to achieve. i have fixed width/height div. and the image contained inside the div is large in size. so i want the image to be draggable inside that div so that the user can see the entire image.

can someone help. pls be a little elaborate about the procedure considering my jquery fluency.

Comment: Do you mean like how Google Maps does it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following;

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  cursor: move;
}

#screen {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="screen">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" class="drag-image" id="draggable" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image doesn't stop dragging at the bounds of the DIV.

Comment: But it does exactly as the user has asked for in the question :)

Comment: can u also tell me how to make the image to stop dragging along its edges. i mean it should snap to the container and there should not be any whitespace visible after the image.

Comment: i am not able to get it to work. the image is not dragging. my markup is exactly same as yours, its just the whole container is set inside another div. also there is another div (with a higher z-index) over the image divs. also as i understand i do not need to "get" the image elements, that is taken care of by the "$", right? also im making the actual "img" element by the DOM. pls help.

Comment: If there is another div above the image with a higher z index then you won't be able to move the image, as the dragging is connected to the image, and you are now trying to move the higher layers div, it's not possible to then move what is below it.

Comment: Snapping to the container would be quite hard, i've played around with it but hadn't managed to get it to work correctly, you'll have to play with some clever css positioning and use the constraint values, it will take quite a bit of tweaking, might be worth setting up another Stackoverflow question for it.

Comment: Regarding your other questions, if you post up some code online then i can try and debug for you :)

Answer (score 9):

You want the jQuery [Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) UI tool. The code for this, as with all jQuery, is very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

Will create a draggable object from a standard html tag (the `IMG` in your case). And for limiting it's mobility to a specific region, you would look into its [containment option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment).

#### Update: *"What is '#draggable' and 'ready'"?*

1. '#draggable' represents the element that you want to be able to drag. The hash (#) symbol represents an ID. When you add your image tags, may give give it an id like the following:
   `<img src="myimage.jpg" id="draggable" />`
   That will make the javascript above make your image draggable, because it has the '#draggable' id that the jQuery is looking for.
2. `'.ready()'` is the method that is automagically raised by your browser once the page is finished loading. Developers are encouraged by the jQuery group to place all jQuery code within this method to ensure all of the elements on the page are completely loaded prior to any jQuery code attempts to manipulate them.

Comment: #draggable is the id of the element.

i.e. <div id="draggable">Content</div>

ready is the Jquery function that executes what ever is within it ( draggable() ) once the DOM is ready i.e. the page is fully rendered.

Answer (score 3):

to limit to a region for this example, containment is not much of a help.
I have implemented this for vertical only scroll, needs enhancement for horizontal limit:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var helper = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
    var h = -(helper.outerHeight() - $(helper).parent().outerHeight());
    if (pos.top >= 0) {
        helper.animate({ top: 0 });
    } else if (pos.top <= h) {
        helper.animate({ top: h });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dragMe').draggable({ containment: 'body' });
```

This code will make it posible to drag the div with the ID of dragMe where ever you want inside the body of the document. You can also write a class or id as containment.

```
$('#dragMe').draggable({ containment: '#container' });
```

This code will make the div dragMe able to be draggable inside of the id container.

Hope this helps otherwise you should be able to find your answer here http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from [PH.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825624/ph) this will provide an elastic bounceback whenever the image is dragged to the point the underlying container is exposed:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
        var helper = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
        var h = -(helper.outerHeight() - $(helper).parent().outerHeight());
        var w = -(helper.outerWidth() - $(helper).parent().outerWidth());
        if (pos.top <= h) {
            helper.animate({ top: h });
        } else if (pos.top > 0) {
            helper.animate({ top: 0 });
        }
        if (pos.left <= w) {
            helper.animate({ left: w });
        } else if (pos.left > 0) {
            helper.animate({ left: 0 });
        }
    }
```