# '$' is undefined javascript error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#WaterMark').draggable(
                    {
                        start: function(e, ui) {
                        },
                        cursor: 'move',
                        zIndex: 2700,
                        revert: 'invalid',
                        containment: '#OriginalImageContainer'
                    });
        $('#OriginalImage').droppable({
            hoverClass: 'DroppableOver',
            drop: InitializeWaterMark
        })
    });

    var InitializeWaterMark = function() {
        var position = $('#WaterMark').position();
        var imgPosition = $('#OriginalImageContainer').position();
        document.getElementById('xpos').value = position.left - imgPosition.left;
        document.getElementById('ypos').value = position.top - imgPosition.top;

    }
    </script>
```

this is a sample javascript code i got regarding drag and drop of images in a asp.net webpage...But it returns a error stating **'$' is undefined**..please help me out

Comment: Are you sure you have included jQuery library correct?

Comment: It looks like the code is using jQuery, and jQuery UI. You'll need to download and include them both before your code.

Comment: An obvious first check: have you included jQuery in your page? The `$` variable isn't stock JavaScript, it's [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: It does not make sense to call document.getElementBydId() when you already use a JS CSS-selector framework like jQuery. $('#xpos).val(position.left - imgPosition.left) will do the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say you were missing the library to support that script (probably jQuery).

You need to include a reference to the JavaScript framework in order to get the draggable functionality you're looking for.

Try adding the following to your page (before the script block in your example):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler-i have included it now it shows. Object doesn't support property or method 'draggable'..can u please help...

Comment: I probably should've guessed that. Try adding a reference to jQuery UI as well. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: As an aside, the examples in this answer retrieve the JavaScript to make the draggable stuff work, but you're probably going to want style sheets and such as well. I recommend you have a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) to see examples of how to theme your elements and for interactive demos on the ways in which you can get your draggable elements to work.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler-thanks it worked ..but after dragging the image over the another it shows.. Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined...thanks for ur help

Answer (score 2):

Include your jQuery and jQuery UI scripts in the page. I tend to use the jQuery and jQuery UI files from a CDN (Content Delivery Network) http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx
Also I have a backup for when the CDN might be down.

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')
```

Then the same with the jQuery UI library.

If the CDN goes down, then it checks to see if jQuery exists and will then use the local version if not.

Answer (score 1):

if it is jquery include problem then put this  tag in head of your aspx page and edit the src attribute in the script tag to point to your copy of jquery.js. For example, if jquery.js is in the same directory as your HTML file, you can use:

You can download your own copy of jQuery from the [Downloading jQuery page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

if you have done correct then explain the scenario little more..

Comment: Niranjan Kala-i referred the code from this site.. its for dragging and dropping a image over another image...http://63.236.73.220/showthread.php?t=644902

Comment: follow this question jquery drag image  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019873