# Prevent image being dragged to desktop, but not while drag and drop reordering

Tags: jquery, image, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am working on a module of drag and drop in CodeIgniter. For better understanding I need to share images:

[image]

The above picture, describes the scenario when I drag by press and holding the blue region which is a li. But now when I drag by pressing and holding an image, this problem occurs:

[image]

The image is getting moved or dragged from the li on which it was residing. It's just getting out of its positioning in li, as such the li remains where it was while the image gets moved.

So I used the following code:

```
$(".img").mousedown(function(){
              return false;
             });
```

where .img is the class of the img src under each li, so that the image wont get dragged from the li.

But now the problem is that, if I drag by pressing and holding the image, the li is also not getting dragged. I want some way in which I can drag the image, and the li will be locked with it, so that I can drag the li by dragging the image. The image should not get dragged alone, the li should also move with it.

Comment: Normally when you enable drag n' drop reordering, the element is stick to the mouse cursor. And that effectively prevents the browser from recognising an 'image drag as url' event.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your answer is here: [jquery drag image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019873/jquery-drag-image)

In other words, do this:

```
$(".img").draggable();
```

And don't forget to include jQuery UI in your HTML file.

Comment: in that case, the image is only getting dragged, the li remains at the same place where it was.. i meant to drag the li by draaging the imagae, and so that the image will not only get dragged, but with it, the li also...

Comment: Than make <li> draggable, not <img> (since it will stay inside of <li>).